# calling constructor from other file

Tags: php, constructor

In a.php

```
if(condition){ 

  include("b.inc");
   b_obj = new b();//this call is not made
   b_obj->a();
}
```

In b.inc

```
class b {

  function b(){ //constructor

    //stmts
  }
  function a(){

    //stmts
  }
}
```

I have this code in php now the constructor of class b is not getting invoked from other file despite of including the file? please help to achieve the calling of constructor in other file.

Answer (score 3):

Change the constructor to __construct(), that's the default constructor in PHP 5 and onwards.

Comment: no errors and the $b_obj->a() is also not working probably because object is not getting created.

Comment: Then I'd question if the b.inc file is being parsed as a PHP file. Try changing the name of the file to b.php and include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the privilege level, make the class / function "public" and then try

or

Try to rename the "b.inc" file to "b.php"

and finally before the b_obj variable add a $ sign

```
b_obj = new b();
b_obj->a();
```

Should be

```
$b_obj = new b();
$b_obj->a();
```